# how can i send sms programmatically in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, sms

I'm new in react native. I want to add a component for sending SMS in my android application and i have tried several different components but every time i got some errors. Is anyone here done this successfully? please help me.

This is the last error I've got.

[image]

Comment: Please add your errors, code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I edited my question and attached error as an image link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend this for sending SMS: https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications

As for the naming collision error, try doing `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` and then restarting the packager with a clear cache: `npm start -- --reset-cache`

If that doesn't work, make sure the version of react-native the SMS package matches the version in your package.

Comment: react-native-communications does not (2.2.1) send SMS programmatically, it merely shows the dialog prefilled with content and wait for user to send by themselves.

Comment: Yeah totally, I've installed it and lost 2 hours before finding out because of this answer.

Comment: I think react-native-communications has a disadvantage so that it isn't working in background, is it?

Answer (score -4):

try this code

```
    String strSmsBody = "Hello";
    //sms recipient id
    String strReceipents = "abc@gmail.com"; 
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    List<String> messages = sms.divideMessage(strSmsBody);
    for (String message : messages) {
        sms.sendTextMessage(strReceipents, null, message, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT), 0), null);
    }
```

dont forget to add this line in manifest file

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thank you but I want a solution for react-native framework. I'm building an android application with react-native framework.